# Is it decidable: is there an input for which turing machine will move its head left?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

$L=\{\langle M \rangle | M $is a Turing machine and  $\exists$ input $x$ such that in $M(x)$ running $M$ moves its head left at least once $\}$

Is $L$ decidable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make tree diagram of possible states and values being read $0,1$. If it moves left its in the set and you have your input. Continue the tree until all current values have occured before, if it hasnt gone left it never will since now it will just loop. The fact that it can write new entries is irrelevant since it cannot go back and read them.

Comment: Doesn't it boil down to the problem "are states after which a machine can move left reachable"? This problem is undecidable.

Comment: I dont understand your comment. Whatever state it reaches it must do so without ever going left, so once you get to the position that all your possible states at stage k have occured before and you have not yet found a left move, you will never find one since it is just a repetition.

Comment: I see your point, I had it myself. But... we know that the problem "a state s is reachable" is not decidable. So that is why the problem "are states after which a machine can move left reachable" should also undecidable... I cannot understand why this argument is wrong.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: say that $M$ is the Turing machine that when reads $0$ goes left and writes $0$, when reads $1$ goes right and writes $1$, with the exception that the initial step is to write $1$. In your tree diagram, there would be a "left move", though this transition can never be triggered.

Comment: @FPE Why won't be transition with left move triggered on input with second symbol $0$, say $00$?

Comment: Just to be clear a machine 1. Reads a square. 2. Writes on that square 3. Moves to a new square in that order. So your machine will move right untill it meets a zero and then goes left.

Comment: the point about my decision process is that after all states and values have repeated, no new states will ever occur.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: well, if you replace the initial step above by going right and writing $1$, the input is erased and the TM writes only $1$s on the tape, right?